# Function does not finish after Parse getDataInBackground is called

Tags: ios, swift, asynchronous, parse-platform

I'm trying to gather data from parse to create an Array of Post objects which will then fill a Table View. I want to create the Post object in such a way that once it is initialized it won't have to rely on the Parse server to get its data back when its Table View cell is dequeued and requeued. However, while the post object is being initialized it never gets past the updataPostImageAndUsername line, which then leads the thread back into the loadTimelinedata which then never reaches the self.timeline.append(post). I tried using completionHandlers which would be called once the asynchronous data retrieval was finished to fix the issue but nothing seems to be working.

Here is the Post class

```
class Post: NSObject {
var data:Dictionary<String,AnyObject>!
var post:PFObject!

init(post: PFObject){
    super.init()
    self.post = post
    data = Dictionary<String,AnyObject>()
    data["content"] = post["content"] as! String
    self.updatePostImageAndUsername({
        (imageData: NSData) in
        self.data["image"] = UIImage(data: imageData)
    })
    self.updatePostDate()

}

private func updatePostImageAndUsername(completionHandler: (imageData:NSData) -> ()){
    let user = post["user"] as! PFUser
    data["postee"] = user.username!
    let imageFile = post["profileImage"] as! PFFile
    imageFile.getDataInBackgroundWithBlock({
        (imageData:NSData?, error: NSError?) in
        if let imageData = imageData {
            completionHandler(imageData: imageData)
        }
    })
}

private func updatePostDate() {
    let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateStyle = NSDateFormatterStyle.ShortStyle
    dateFormatter.timeStyle = .ShortStyle
    data["createdAt"] = dateFormatter.stringFromDate(post.createdAt!)
}
```

}

And here is where I create the Post's

```
class TimelineTableViewController: UITableViewController {
var timelineData = [Post]()

/////////////////
///Data Functions
/////////////////

func loadTimelinedata(completionHandler: (post: PFObject) -> ()) {
    self.timelineData.removeAll()
    let posts = PFQuery(className: "Posts")
        posts.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock({
        (objects: [PFObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
        if let objects = objects {
            for object in objects {
                completionHandler(post: object)
            }
        }
    })

}

override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
    loadTimelinedata({
        (post: PFObject) in
        let post = Post(post: post)
        self.timelineData.append(post)
    })
}
```

So basically my question is why do these functions exit once getDataInBackground is finished?

Comment: Maybe `findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock` is returning an error? Having said that, I would have the completion handler in `loadTimelinedata` return an array of PFObjects, rather than one at a time.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, but after checking there is still no error.

Comment: Rereading your code, if `getDataInBackgroundWithBlock` returns an error (or at least imageData is nil), you will get the effect you are seeing. Have you checked the `if let` is running and passing?

Comment: I just did some more tests and actually at the imageFile variable i needed to switch post to user, but even after fixing that when the code reaches that variable declaration it stops and exits the function without giving me an error. And I know there is a file at that key because I use it in a profileViewController to get there picture.